# HTML file with Javascript - Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, pandas

I really need help with this. I have to read thousands of HTML files to extract values to a dataset but the HTM file has javascrip and pandas is getting me the name of the variable instead of the value.The code I have used is very simple, use pandas to read it and then look for the tables it found.
I will share a link for the HML file, and the code and an image of the value I am trying to get.
Thank you.

```
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OperationsMD/powermill/main/Project_Summary.html"
import pandas as pd

df_mill = pd.read_html(url)
print(df_mill[2])
```

And I get: 0  verificar tempo when I should get: Tempo Total: 03:09:09 that I show in the image.

[image]

Comment: Can anyone help, please ? I really need this and I have been struggling for weeks and oly got closer with beautifulsoup but couldnt really solve it.

Comment: Where does the variable `TotalTime` come from? Can you update your post to be conformant with the [mre] guidelines by, at the very least, including a minimal example of the source files on which you’re attempting to use this code?

Comment: Hi @esqew, the totalTime comes from the HTML file I gave the link, if you open it you will see some javascripr in there and that variable. The url in the code contains the file.

Comment: Questions must be self-contained here; they shouldn’t be reliant on external sources to illustrate a problem since those links frequently change/break and zero out any value for future visitors to this question. Please include the requisite source to reproduce as a [mre].

Comment: I understand what you're saying but in this case I need to read an HTMLfile with javascript in it, and theres more than a thousand lines there so I cant do it without the link for the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but the HTM file has javascrip and pandas is getting me the name of the variable instead of the value.

That means... you need to actually execute the JavaScript part in order to get those values.
While [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) is great for handling structured data, like tables in an HTML page, it does not execute JavaScript code. Therefore, it will not be able to retrieve the values set by JavaScript.

One possible approach would be to use [selenium 4.9.1](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/), the Python language bindings for Selenium WebDriver: a Python library that allows you to automate browser actions.
Selenium will actually load the webpage in a real browser, execute any JavaScript, and then allow you to access the resulting DOM (Document Object Model), including any modifications made by JavaScript.

The following is an example of how you might use Selenium to retrieve the value you're looking for:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

# path to the chromedriver executable
chromedriver_path = '/path/to/chromedriver'

# create a new browser session
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path)

# direct the driver to the webpage
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OperationsMD/powermill/main/Project_Summary.html"
driver.get(url)

# get the value of a JavaScript variable
total_time = driver.execute_script("return totalTime;")

# print the value
print(total_time)

# end the Selenium browser session
driver.quit()
```

This code starts a new browser session, navigates to the desired webpage, and then retrieves the value of the `totalTime` JavaScript variable.

Do replace '`/path/to/chromedriver`' with the path where you've installed the ChromeDriver. You can [download the ChromeDriver from here](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/).

That is a valid approach for *one* page. For a thousands... you might encounter resource issues, so test it incrementally! (And in a way which does not look like a DDos attack ;) Do not do too many requests in too little time).

Comment: Thank you @VonC, the files are local HTML files, do you think I will have the DDos attack issue either ? The resources I had that issue already using pandas will have to limit the number of pages per day and yes I have thousands of pages to extract values.

Comment: @Dini It depends on how many requests you will be doing to that remote site. If you stay within the limit, that should be fine.

Comment: maybe I did not explain myself right, all the files are locally, they are in the server but in the hard disk , they just are stored as HTMl files like an csv.

Comment: @Dini Then there should be no ddos issue. (Unless the JavaScript part makes a remote call)

Answer (score 2):

First of all i believe this is not the best way to solve this problem. I used selenium web driver to execute javascript. Since the data is hidden behind xml file, i converted it to html then opened the html object with selenium. This allowed the browser to execute the JavaScript. For driver i used undetected_chromedriver since it was easier for me to install.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OperationsMD/powermill/main/Project_Summary.html"
Doc = requests.get(url)
Con = Doc.content 
soup_obj = BeautifulSoup(Con , "lxml") 
driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True)
driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + str(soup_obj))


tableData = driver.find_element(By.ID,"pdTime")
df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)

print(df[1])
# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

Don't forget to install selenium.

Comment: That seems more detailed than my pseudo-code. Upvoted.